# Split a string into a List<string>

Tags: c#, arrays, list, split

I am trying to split a `string` into a `List<string>`. I have this string:

```
string myData = "one, two, three; four, five, six; seven, eight, nine";
```

And I would like the filled list of strings to look like:

```
one two three
four five six
seven eight nine
```

Meaning that I have to remove the commas(`,`) and the semi colons(`;`), so that for example the first row of the list, the second column will be two(without commas, semi colons or spaces).

I know that I can use `.Split`:

```
string[] splittedArray = myData.Split(';').ToArray();
```

This should produce a result like:

```
one, two, three,
four, five, six,
seven, eight, nine
```

How do I remove the commas(`,`) and put it in the list in that format?

Comment: You can use [Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) to replace the commas with nothing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
myData.Replace(",", String.Empty).Split(';').ToList();
```

Comment: Use `String.Empty` for the empty string. You know, just in case an empty string ever would look any different. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 string myData = "one, two, three; four, five, six; seven, eight, nine";
                string[] splittedArray = myData.Replace(",", "").Split(';').ToArray();
                List<string> list = splittedArray.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] splittedArray = myData.Split(';')
                        .Select(x => x.Replace(",","")
                        .ToArray();
```

Or:

```
string[] splittedArray = myData.Split(';')
                        .Select(x => string.Join(" ", x.Split(','))
                        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
 string myData = "one, two, three; four, five, six; seven, eight, nine";
 List<string> list = myString.Replace(", ", " ").Split(';').ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use one more `Split`

```
var splittedArray = myData.Split(';').Select(s => s.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
```

So `splittedArray[0][1]` will be `two`